# why method overriding does not check method signature when using generics?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

for example, we know that the following is not allowed because overriding need the same method signature.

```
class Parent{
  void f(Parent p){}
}

class Son extends Parent{
 @Override//not allowed ,change the signature
 void f(Son s){} 
}
```

However, if we use generics, like

```
class Parent<T extends Parent>{
  void f(T p){}
}

class Son extends Parent<Son>{
 @Override//ok 
 void f(Son s){} 
}
```

then it is allowed , but why?

Comment: Because the first one isn't an override, it is an overload. You were already told that several times last time you posted this.

Comment: The second example doesn't work either because of invalid syntax. Try again.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I know the first is overload, which is post here just as a comparation.  The key point is why the second is override but not overload.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I just cannot understand why somebody just close the question or downvote without even understanding what people really want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f(Parent p)` and `void f(Son s)` are different methods, having different *signatures*. Since they have the same *name*, if is referred to as *overloading*.

Generics is the compiler playing tricks with the JVM. When you define `Parent<T extends Parent>` and `f(T p)`, the compiler will be able to *pretend* that `T` can be any sub-type of `Parent`, depending on the type argument specified for `T` when `Parent` is referenced.

To the JVM, the method is still created as `f(Parent p)`, since that is the *bound* for `T`. This is what *type erasure* is about.

When you then declare `Son extends Parent<Son>`, the compiler *pretends* that `f(T p)` was declared as `f(Son p)`, which would make `f(Son s)` method of class `Son` an override of the `f` method in `Parent`. However, that is just the compiler pretending, the JVM only sees method `f(Parent p)` in the super-type, so the `f` in `Son` is not an override of the `f` method in `Parent`.

To implement the pretended view of the world that generics has added to the Java language, the compiler solves the discrepancy by creating a **bridge method**. The result is that, after type-erasure, the runtime code seen by the JVM will be:

```java
class Parent {
    void f(Parent p) {}
}

class Son extends Parent {
    @Override
    bridge synthetic void f(Parent p) {
        this.f((Son) p);
    }

    void f(Son s) {}
}
```

`bridge` and `synthetic` are of course not keywords you can use in Java source code, but they are internal *modifiers* specified on the method in the bytecode.

As you can see, if someone has a `Parent<Son> parent = new Son();` variable and calls `parent.f(son)`, the hidden bridge method will *redirect* the call to the `f(Son s)` method.

It is all the **compiler playing tricks** to fit the Java language into the bytecode that the JVM executes.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions for Overloading :

1.Both must have the same method name.

2.Both must have different argument lists.

3.Have different return types.

4.Have different access modifiers.

5.Throw different checked or unchecked exceptions.

Your Second code Fails to meet condition number 2.

T is a type.  means anything that is of type Parent **or** its subclass is acceptable. ie, Son(Subclass) or Parent(Parent)

So, Due to Same Argument lists. It is considered as Overriding.